# How can i get results from two MySql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables :

```
--------------------------
USER
------------------
id  | name | email
------------------
 1  | w    |  w@g
------------------
 2  | x    |  x@g
-----------------
 3  | y    |  y@g
------------------
 4  | z    |  z@g
------------------

FRIENDS
-----------------------
user | friend | status |
-----------------------
 1   |  2     | friend
-----------------------
 1   |  3     | requested
-----------------------
```

Here in FRIENDS table, **w** is friend of **x** and **y**.

**What i want** :
I want to get all records including user friends status in my search query.

```
Expected Results:
------------------------------
id  | name | email |  status  |
------------------------------
 2  | x    | x@g   |  friend  |
------------------------------
 3  | y    | y@g   |  requested |
------------------------------
 4  | z    | z@g   |   null    |
------------------------------
```

**What i tried**

```
SELECT * FROm `user` AS A INNER JOIN friends AS B ON A.id = B.user WHERE A.firstName LIKE '%e%'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you are asking for a join query, please write your expected result too.

Comment: @Alpac check now question pz

Comment: Please show us the  query you have so far. Where do you fail?

Comment: I guess it's because this is a very basic question that you would find answered here or in Google. And you don't show any effort of your own. Usually you would try and then fail somehow and ask for specific help here, rather than saying: I want this or that be done, and I want you to do it for me.

Comment: @Dear Thorsten, i did search ..But i didn't find my solution.
Check my question again.

Comment: @Alll
If u can't answer my question, then no need to down vote.If u have ability ,then answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you want to show user data (name etc.), so select from user. You want to show their friends status related to user 1 with it, so join accordingly. As they can have a friends status related to user 1 or not, but you want to show them anyway, you cannot use an inner join, but need an outer join. At last exclude user 1 itself from the results in the where clause.

```
select u.*, f.status
from user u
left join friends f on f.friend = u.id and f.user = 1
where u.id <> 1
```

EDIT (after acceptance): If you want all users matching certain criteria (say firstname like '%e%'), then your results would have to contain that user, too, to give sense to the data shown. So you would have to query the user table twice. In order to do that, I would first combine all users matching that criteria with all others (i.e. other user ID), and then left join the friend relation.

```
select user_self.*, user_other.*, f.status
from user user_self
join user user_other on user_other.id <> user_self.id
left outer join friends f on and f.user = user_self.id and f.friend = user_other.id
where user_self.firstname like '%e%';
```

Remove the WHERE clause if you want all users with all relations.

Comment: Hi, Thanks, Here is what i want. I modified your query and is working.
select u.*, f.status from user u left join friends f on f.friend = u.id and f.user = 1 where u.id <> 1 AND u.lastName LIKE '%ik%'

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I wrote the query to match user 1, to meet your example. If you want to select another user, you will have to replace `1` in my query, e.g. with `(select id from user where lastname like '%ik%')` in both places. If your criteria can even match more than one user, you should extend your results to show these users, too. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Oops, now I see. You want to show only some users (those who match '%ik%'). Then yes, your modified query is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You need a simple join:

```
SELECT * FROM 
USER U INNER JOIN FRIENDS F
ON U.id = F.user
```